# Regular Expression to match colon but not backslash colon

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm searching for a PCRE for PHP to match a colon but not a backslash colon (`\:`).
I tried this but it isn't working cause as I know now the `^\\` will match any char except backslash.

```
/[^\\\]:/
```

I need to get only colons and no escaped colons.

Comment: Would `\ + \ + :` match? Might be the start of a string parser.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to match the previous character, use negative lookbehind:

```
/(?<!\\):/
```

Note that you'll have to do some extra escaping when using the above expression as a PHP string because you have to escape the backslashes for both PHP and PCRE:

```
'/(?<!\\\\):/'
```

The advantage of this is that it will match a colon at the beginning of a string, and it won't capture any extra characters.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the third backslash:

`/[^\\]:/`

Tested with this string:

`This : is : a \: test`

You get the first two colons as the result.

Comment: What Manu just said.  Depending on if you're using php and this experession is in a single-quoted string, you may need to re-add the backslash so the string doesn't have a parse error. Nothing to do with the PCRE, just the PHP string.